# Ctrl + Dot (ShowSmartTag) not working in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm now using the Visual Studio 2012, and now the keyboard shortcut for "ShowSmartTag", <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>, is not working. I googled a bit found someone said that [CodeRush's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeRush) Quick Nav shortcut is the same, so I disabled that command in CodeRush, but still I can not fix this. I also tried to disable all those suspicious extensions, but still no success. Any idea?

Comment: Might be related too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156296/resharper-removes-the-ctrl-quickactions-tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's CodeRush that caused the issue and I uninstalled it, then SmartTag works again. My guess is that CodeRush replaced VS2012's built-in SmartTag entirely.

Comment: That's what I was saying: "Some extensions might "merge" their tools with VS tools". That was why i thought you should try to [disable the CodeRush Smart Tags](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CodeRush/CustomDocument8229)...

Comment: Yes, but problem is that even if I did disable Smart Tags in CodeRush options, the Ctrl + Dot won't work. So I was left with no option but to uninstall CodeRush

Answer (score 16):

All keyboard shortcuts can be viewed from `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard`. What does your `View.ShowSmartTag` command say about current shortcuts?

[image: Keyboard Options]

If you try to assign <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to anything, it will tell you if the shortcut is used by something else...

Comment: @peter, I actually already tried to see whether the shortcut is assigned correctly, found out that it was correct. Now I tried to assign Ctrl + . to View.ShowSmartTag again, it shows that this shortcut is used by Image.SmallBrush(VC Image Editor) and View.ShowSmartTag

Comment: @peter, odd things happened, I changed the View.ShowSmartTag's shortcut to Ctrl + Alt + ., still no success. Completely confused here.

Comment: @peter, but on the other hand, I'm able to use mouse to hover to show the smart tag, it's just weird

Comment: In what scope did you define the shortcuts? Just to be safe, make it *global*... Also, you mentioned CodeRush, what other extensions are you using? Some extensions might "merge" their tools with VS tools or override VS shortcuts. Could it be something like this [CodeRush Smart Tags](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CodeRush/CustomDocument8229) thing that's blocking the shortcut?

Comment: I thought it might be, but if so then why is that I changed the shortcut to Ctrl + Alt + Dot and it still does not work. Also I am making the shortcut global. Also I tried with Shift + Alt + F10 which is another global shortcut for SmartTag, so I'm lost here.

BTW, my shortcut for SmartTag is the same as yours.

Comment: I have the same issue :( and I think it's not related with keyboard shortcut conflict. What I noticed is that something's blocking the popup from being shown.

Comment: I uninstalled CodeRush and then the Ctrl + Dot comes back. I now think maybe CodeRush replaced VS2012's built-in SmartTag entirely.

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was [Web Essentials](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/web-essentials/info) that caused this issue. I disabled it, and now all works well.

Comment: I disabled web essentials and got back show SmartTag.  I re-enabled web essentials and was still able to use SmartTag.  I rebuilt my machine recently and am wondering if I might have installed Web Essentials prior to VS Update 2, thereby causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks, in my case it was Microsoft Web Developer Tools

Comment: I suspected it was one of my addins also, so I disabled Web Essentials and it still didn't work. However, after I restarted my computer, the shortcut started working also. My Web Essentials is enabled right now and everything works perfectly fine, so if restarting is an option for you, I would recommend you try that before disabling any of the addins.

Answer (score 1):

On my PC the problem occurs mostly when renaming a method or a parameter ...

To analyze this I have started a first VS 2012 instance without starting to edit the source code. 
Then I have started a second instance of VS 2012 which must be attached to the first VS instance:

- Debug->Attach to Process
- Look for devenv.exe, Title = title of the VS main window
- Select Managed and Native Code
- Attach

Enable Break when exception occurs:

- Debug->Exceptions
- Enable C++ Exceptions, Common Language Runtime Exceptions
- OK

Now as I started to edit a parameter name in the first VS instance, an error was thrown and the debugger in the second instance showed me an error in an memory Profiler Add-In.
After I have uninstalled the Add-in, the ShowSmartTag called by the keyboard works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>, and I try this hotkey in anywhere of Visual Studio, but it is useless. My notebook is ThinkPad T430 made in Vietnam; I think this is an issue by the keyboard standard.

Maybe you should set another hotkey for "ShowSmartTag". For example, I removed the "NavigateTo" and added the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to "ShowSmartTag".

Comment: The problem with my machine is that no matter what hotkey I assign, it just wouldn't work. So I uninstalled CodeRush Xpress altogether