# Keyboard shortcut for the "Update options..." variable drop down in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

In VS 2012 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> would enter the drop down that is highlighted at the bottom right of a variable name when the name itself is changed. You could then update all references to the variable with the keyboard only. I cannot get this to work in VS 2013, and am missing it greatly! Does anyone have any idea how to get this working in 2013??

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard. The command you're looking for is View.ShowSmartTag.

You can then assign the shortcut you want (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>) to this command.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/). It has all the keyboard shortcuts available for VS2013. Including Ctrl + Dot
If it still does not work, have a look at the configuration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358051/ctrl-dot-showsmarttag-not-working-in-vs2012)  (This is for VS2012, but I would imagine its' is the same for 2013)