# Resharper removes the CTRL + . QuickActions tasks

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

So I'm finally giving ReSharper a try, and so far it's not too bad, but it does seem to replace a lot of key bindings. I've kept the original VS key bindings, and each time I'm asked what I want to do when a conflict keybinding exists, which is cool.

Except, I seem to have lost my CTRL+. QuickActions window/dialog/dropdown thing. I use this religiously for renaming methods, and implementing interfaces.

I've tried resetting the VS options > key binding for 'View.QuickActions' to be CTRL + ., but nothing happens when I enter that shortcut. Also, nothing happens when I right click on something an select Quick Actions from the context menu.

Is there some new ReSharper "QuickActions" that I can implement, or what is the keybindings for renaming variables/methods/classes etc, and implementing interfaces?

Comment: Can you let me know which Visual Studio and ReSharper version you were on when you created this question? I tried to reproduce this on VS2015 with ReSharper 9.2, and pressing Ctrl+. triggered ReSharper's Alt+Enter menu with Visual Studio's own suggestions mixed up with ReSharper's suggestions - all as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I needed VS quick actions bulb / screwdriver back so I could use a neat [extension for generating mappings](https://github.com/cezarypiatek/MappingGenerator), and found that

```
ReSharper > Options > Code Inspection > Settings, and disable "Do not show Visual Studio bulb".
```

Worked - I now get both.

Comment: @Jura Gorohovsky Thanks - got that from your comment - thought worthy of an actual answer as works for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works very well now.

Answer (score 10):

Current versions of ReSharper (tested with 2019.3) have an option (disabled by default) which merges all Visual Studio quick actions into ReSharpers quick action menu:

```
Extensions/ReSharper/Options
- Environment/Editor/Visual Studio Features
  - Merge Visual Studio light bulb actions into ReSharper action indicator
```

If you also enable the following option

```
  - Show Visual Studio light bulb actions in submenu
```

the "classic" Visual Studio quick actions can be found in a "Roslyn actions" submenu:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That's a perfect combination of settings. I know why Jetbrains did it this way by default but sometimes Roslyn just gives better hints than them.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and ReSharper v9.2.  Unfortunately, on the [ReSharper blog here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/07/21/resharper-9-1-2-for-visual-studio-2015-rtm/) for v9.1.2 they indicate that:

> *The major issue with 9.1.1 is that it is blocking Visual Studio’s
>   quick actions: whenever both ReSharper and Visual Studio detect a
>   problem and provide a fix, you don’t have a way to choose Visual
>   Studio’s quick action over ReSharper’s.*

In my experience even if there is no ReSharper issue on the line the Visual Studio quick action will not work; for example, with Visual Studio Spell Checker extension finding a spelling mistake in a comment - ReSharper obviously has no problem with that line of code, the Quick Action is visible and works with the mouse, but the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+. doesn't work.

According to the same post:

> ReSharper 9.1.2 merges its own quick-fixes and other contextually available
>   actions with Visual Studio’s own quick actions into its Alt+Enter menu

However - at least in the case of the spelling mistake in a comment - the ReSharper Ctrl+Enter menu doesn't see anything worth fixing on that line and so that solution doesn't work.

Here's hoping ReSharper v9.3 fixes the problem!

Comment: Robert, specifically with Visual Studio Spell Checker extension the problem is that even in VS2015 it makes use of older smart tags to show their corrections while ReSharper only integrates suggestions based on the newer, VS2015-specific quick actions mechanism. For a workaround, please go to ReSharper > Options > Code Inspection > Settings, and disable "Do not show Visual Studio bulb". This will help show Spell Checker's actions on Ctrl+. and ReSharper's own actions on Alt+Enter. As an alternative, you can install ReSharper's own spell checking plug-in called Respeller.

Answer (score 3):

Change your Resharper options to match this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For those who do it in 2023 - it's known bug and not working right now, we have to wait fix:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-486822/VS-actions-are-not-shown-in-R-Alt-Enter-menu-in-VS-2022?_gl=1*zduwmi*_ga*MTM0MDg0Nzk1Mi4xNjc1MzQ4Mjc0*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTY4MzM3MjgwNC4xMC4wLjE2ODMzNzI4MDQuMC4wLjA.&_ga=2.3819449.824536250.1683372805-1340847952.1675348274

P.S. However where is a working workaround - disable `Hide Visual Studio Quick Action icons in the left editor margin` feature, and use different context menu.