# How can I find the namespace for a C# class?

Tags: c#, namespaces

Totally new to C# but have to write some code. e.g. In this sample, https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Getting-Started, HttpBasicAuthenticator class is not found, I need to add a using "namespace", but don't know which namespace this class belong to. Is there a place I can search?

Comment: Did you add a `using RestSharp;` line as shown under "Basic Usage"?

Comment: Have you installed the Nuget-Package? [RestSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp)

Comment: @JirongHu see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Premise: you can find class namespace above its declaration.

If you want to add reference of a x namespace from your class and you work on Visual Studio, just point the cursor on class name (i.e. "HttpBasicAuthenticator") and hit "CTRL + ."

A menu should open in which you can add the reference to HttpBasicAuthenticator class.

PS
If you still can't see a reference to a already existence class, try adding the right reference from your project

Comment: CTRL + . doesn't work on my VS 2012, nothing pops up.

Comment: Take a lot at this response
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358051/ctrl-dot-showsmarttag-not-working-in-vs2012

Answer (score 0):

In this case is really easy since you have the repository for the class. So you could search the class name in github the find the code file associated with that class and get the name space from there.

[image]

**Update based on your comment**

For general cases you have to be sure you have a reference to a dll containing that class. Then you could right click on the dll and select `View in Object Browser`.

[image]

Then in the popup window you will be able to search by the class name.

[image]

If the class name exists you will see the container namespace in bottom right panel.

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem, but I am asking a generic case.